# How to install audit2allow on Alpine Linux 3.5?

Tags: audit, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I am coming from an `apt-get` background and am now trying (and failing) to use Alpine Linux's apk utility for package management.

I try running `apk install audit2allow` and end up with a help message that culminates with the line "This apk has coffee making abilities."

**How can I install the audit2allow utility on Alpine Linux?**

Comment: There is no package by that name in the official alpine repository. You could check https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org if there is a package for what you want with a similar name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because apk uses “add” instead of “install”